# Unwind segues not working with modal view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm working on a storyboard-based iPhone app.
I am successfully using unwind segues to navigate my stack of view controllers.

However, when I present a modal view controller I cannot seem to be able to trigger the unwind segue that I have specified in the storyboard file.

Is this normal or a bug?

Comment: Probably it's the normal behavior. Please elaborate with more details and a storyboard screenshot if possible.

Comment: for modal views use dismissviewcontrolleranimated

Comment: I have no problem using 'dismissviewcontrolleranimated'. 
However, I'm trying to determine why the unwind functionality is not working in this case. I can find nothing pertinent in Apple's documentation.

Comment: I am using unwind segues in modal views without issues. What problem do you have exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Apparently I've hit some glitch with the storyboard editor.
What I did was to delete the destination (modal) view controller and then re-create it.

Works fine, now.
Bug report filed.

Answer (score 0):

So I have the same problem (more than two years later!).  I haven't fixed the underlying issue, but I found that a modal view being presented with a default presentation style will unwind OK, but one that uses a page sheet presentation style simply doesn't work.  The `unwindToViewX` method gets called on the parent view controller that the unwind segue is moving to, though, so I've circumvented the issue with the following code:

```
if (self.presentedViewController) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This saves me from setting up a delegate system as the unwind action is doing all the heavy lifting, but also avoids an issue where perhaps the unwind action might work one day, because in that case `self.presentedViewController` should return `NO` because the unwind action worked correctly and we won't end up dismissing two view controllers by accident.

I hope this helps others in the same boat, but I'd also like to hear if anyone else has better solutions.